# How to copy array from File1.java to File two.java

Tags: java, arrays

In File1.java I have-

```
public static int[] dataArray = new int[100];
```

in File2.java I am accessing it as -

```
private static int[] data = new int[File1.dataArray.length];
for(int i=0; i<File1.dataArray.length; i++) {
        if(File1.array1[i] == 0)
            continue;
        data[i] = File1.array1[i];}
```

Is this the right way or can I do like this-

```
private static int[] data = File1.dataArray;
```

to copy it? Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do

```
private static int[] data = File1.dataArray;
```

But there is a HUGE DANGER doing it that way and therefore I wouldn't call it the right way to COPY arrays, because you are not REALLY copying.

See this code. It demonstrates what happens.

```
public class File1
 {
    public static int[] dataArray = new int[100]; 

    static  
     {
  for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
     dataArray[i] = i;
    }
     }

}

public class File2
 {
   private static int[] data = File1.dataArray; // makes "data" refer to the SAME array as File1.dataArray

   public static void main(String[] args)
    {
  File2 file2 = new File2();

      file2.data[20] = -567;  // this changes File1.dataArray also!

      System.out.println(File1.dataArray[20]); // prints -567
    } 
 }
```

Therefore, use System.arrayCopy() to copy arrays, as Jarrod suggested. Of course, you can also copy by writing your own code like this -

```
 private static int[] data = new int[File1.dataArray.length];

 static
  {   
    for(int i = 0; i < File1.dataArray.length; i++)
 {
    data[i] = File1.dataArray[i];   
 }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that explanation! That was pretty much the answer I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 0):

Look up [System.arraycopy()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) to copy arrays.

It isn't clear what the presented code has to do with Files as referenced in your title?

Also your presented code is incomplete, won't compile and isn't clear or idiomatic Java.

This will most likely get closed if you don't make it clearer what you want to do.

Comment: my bad, Both the arrays are present in different java file with their names File1.java and File2.java